# How to fetch records between a given date range and both date range should include for searching records?

Tags: sql, database, oracle

Here is the Query:

```
SELECT DECODE(AVSR.INFORMATIONTYPE,'NULL','UNKNOWN','5','Infectious Agent Transmission Issue','4','Environmental Issue','3','Withdrawal Period Issue','2','Lack OF Expected Efficacy','1','Safety Issue') Infotype,
  COUNT(VM.Vaer_No),
  AVSR.INFORMATIONTYPE
FROM AGVET_VAE_INFO VM,
  Agvet_Vae_Safetyreport AVSR
WHERE AVSR.RECORD_ID          = VM.FK_AVSR_REC_ID
AND VM.Vaer_Delete            = 0
AND VM.Archived               = 0
AND VM.E2B_MESSAGE_LIST_TYPE <> 01
AND VM.IMPORT_FLAG           <> 1
AND AVSR.ORIGINALRECEIVEDATE BETWEEN to_date ('2000/04/1', 'yyyy/mm/dd') AND to_date ('2000/04/28', 'yyyy/mm/dd')+1
GROUP BY AVSR.INFORMATIONTYPE
```

In this query it is displaying records 2000/04/29 also.But i need records only from `2000/04/1` to `2000/04/28` (Inclusive both dates).

Comment: Then why are you adding +1 to the end date?  "between" clause is inclusive.

Comment: remove `+1` at the end. it is increasing one day from second `to_date()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Using `trunc`

```
AND trunc(AVSR.ORIGINALRECEIVEDATE) BETWEEN to_date ('2000/04/1', 'yyyy/mm/dd') AND to_date ('2000/04/28', 'yyyy/mm/dd')
```

but this will ignore if any index is there on column `AVSR.ORIGINALRECEIVEDATE`, use it if there are no index on this column or if there is functional index using function `trunc`

2) using `>=` and `<`

```
AND (AVSR.ORIGINALRECEIVEDATE >= to_date ('2000/04/1', 'yyyy/mm/dd') AND AVSR.ORIGINALRECEIVEDATE < (to_date ('2000/04/28', 'yyyy/mm/dd') + 1))
```

3) using timestamp

```
AND AVSR.ORIGINALRECEIVEDATE BETWEEN to_date ('2000/04/1 00:00:00', 'yyyy/mm/dd hh24:mi:ss') AND to_date ('2000/04/28 23:59:59', 'yyyy/mm/dd hh24:mi:ss')
```

Answer (score 1):

remove the +1 from the second date

```
SELECT DECODE(AVSR.INFORMATIONTYPE,'NULL','UNKNOWN','5','Infectious Agent Transmission Issue','4','Environmental Issue','3','Withdrawal Period Issue','2','Lack OF Expected Efficacy','1','Safety Issue') Infotype,
  COUNT(VM.Vaer_No),
  AVSR.INFORMATIONTYPE
FROM AGVET_VAE_INFO VM,
  Agvet_Vae_Safetyreport AVSR
WHERE AVSR.RECORD_ID          = VM.FK_AVSR_REC_ID
AND VM.Vaer_Delete            = 0
AND VM.Archived               = 0
AND VM.E2B_MESSAGE_LIST_TYPE <> 01
AND VM.IMPORT_FLAG           <> 1
AND AVSR.ORIGINALRECEIVEDATE BETWEEN to_date ('2000/04/1', 'yyyy/mm/dd') AND to_date ('2000/04/28', 'yyyy/mm/dd')
GROUP BY AVSR.INFORMATIONTYPE
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to remove the `+1` because [BETWEEN](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/conditions011.htm#SQLRF52147) includes the two limits:

> expr1 BETWEEN expr2 AND expr3
>
> is the value of the boolean expression:
>
> expr2 <= expr1 AND expr1 <= expr3